# Can sealed epiphyseal growth plates theoretically be restored via epigenetic or genetic methods?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, human-genetics

I know that epiphyseal growth plates seal up once people become young adults and that it is currently impossible to restore them to actively produce new bone growth but, is it theoretically possible via genetic or epigenetic means to reactivate them to produce new bone?

Comment: I don't know about bone length, that's one for science fiction. What about bone density?

Comment: bone density is something else I'd be interested in knowing about but this question is focused only on reactivating the epiphyseal growth plates.